# Parse hash parameters from request URL

Tags: java, url, servlets

I did a web application in Java on Tomcat container. I have a url string

```
http://XXXXXXXXXX:8082/App/login#access_token=b8ee9e9707c54a8e23bdc224dfdae&expires_in=3600
```

How can I parse that string and read a hash value (the value after #) from `HttpServletRequest`?

Note : the URL string is from `HttpServletRequest`, I didn't get this full URL dirctly from request by `request.getRequestURI`

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp ="http://XXXXXXXXXX:8082/App/login#access_token=b8ee9e9707c54a8e23bdc224dfdae&expires_in=3600";
temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf("#"), temp.indexOf("&", temp.lastIndexOf("#")));
```

cheers!

Comment: url string is from HttpServletRequest, i didn't get this full url  dirctly from reques by request.getRequestURI.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is having all you need:
[here](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

Comment: i have to parse from java servlet

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java on back end.